# PHP: How to make Rakit Validation use default value when input field doesn't match other rules?

Tags: php, validation

I'm trying to set up validation using Rakit/Validation library.

```php
$validator = new \Rakit\Validation\Validator;
$in = ["port" => -1];
$validation = $validator->validate($in, [
    'port' => 'default:80|integer|between:0,65535',
]);
$errors = $validation->errors();
print_r($errors->firstOfAll());
```

The problem is that instead of the `port` variable reseting to the default (80), I get an error message "The Port must be between 0 and 65535".

Is it possible to make rules use the default value if passed value failed to pass checks? Or I would have to write custom rules?

Answer (score 0):

According to rakits documentation:

> It just set default value to your attribute if that attribute is empty or not present.

So it doesn't work when the values is set and therefore not if the value is invalid.

Comment: you could write your own rule. https://github.com/rakit/validation#registeroverride-rule